# МОРФОСЕМАНТИКА

Tags: семантика

Здравствуйте всем. Я из Турции. Я изучаю русский язык и литературу. Я хочу спросить у вас, что такое морфосемантика? Что она изучает? Какой у неё предмет? Она  изучает текст с точки зрения грамматико-семантики? Вы можете дать мне информацию о ней, пожалуйста! 
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 5):

В филологии есть такое понятие - морфо-семантическое поле - вся совокупность лексических связей, определяющих возникновение слова, т.е. словообразование, этимология, а также отношения омонимии, паронимии, синонимии, антонимии.

Морфосемантика - семантика (лексическое значение) морфов, в основном корней. Вот в этимологическом словаре даётся всё словообразовательное гнездо - что от чего образовалось и какое значение приобрело, это и есть морфосемантика.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Кажется, это трудная тема, чтобы написать диссертацию о нем, и к тому же нет информации об этой теме в Интернете.

Comment: Ну, искать в Интернете материал для диссертации - нонсенс. Диссертация - ваше исследование. Берёте интересное слово и исследуете его, давая полный лексический, этимологический, словообразовательный анализ, примеры употребления лучше брать в художественной литературе.Делаете вывод.

Comment: Конечно, я не искаю материал для диссертации в Интернете. Только, я хотела  узнать пока что-то об этом термине до приезда в Россию, потому что нет русскоязычных источников в Турции. 